# How to solve 404 "The resource cannot be found" error in web api application after publishing on Godaddy server

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am facing a problem in which i am facing error of 404 after publishing my application on Godaddy server before publishing it. It was working fine I just change connection string for server and publish it and in server it is giving 500 error and in my application it is giving 404 error.

I am pasting the connection string which I replace and I try every possible thing change in connection string but I did not get any thing.

Old connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Prasadseed-20190925022122.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Prasadseed-20190925022122;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PrasadSeedDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PrasadSeed.csdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeed.ssdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeed.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ranu;initial catalog=PrasadSeedDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="PrasadSeedDBEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PrasadSeedDB.csdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeedDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeedDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Ranu;initial catalog=PrasadSeedDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My new connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString=" Data Source=43.255.152.21;Integrated Security=False;User ID=Prasadseed; Password=********; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PrasadSeedDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PrasadSeed.csdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeed.ssdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeed.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ranu;initial catalog=PrasadSeedDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="PrasadSeedDBEntities1" connectionString="Data Source=43.255.152.21;Integrated Security=False;User ID=Prasadseed; Password=*********; " providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

and my web.config file is now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Prasadseed-20190925022122.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Prasadseed-20190925022122;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PrasadSeedDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PrasadSeed.csdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeed.ssdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeed.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ranu;initial catalog=PrasadSeedDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="PrasadSeedDBEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PrasadSeedDB.csdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeedDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.PrasadSeedDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Ranu;initial catalog=PrasadSeedDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>

      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />





    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /></handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you setup your default page? If this is 500 internal server error, you need to check full error message on the server.

Comment: i have set my default page and how to see full error message

Comment: What is the full error message on the server?

Comment: this is link my site please see it and help me http://tpwprintyard.com/

Comment: Could you please make sure that you have published your site properly? The connection string?

Comment: @DouglasThomas connection string in proper way sir

Comment: Are you using Plesk too, right? Please refer to https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-using-web-deploy-with-plesk-control-panel/

Comment: @DouglasThomas i publish it by making Zip file and by using plesk and ftp account

Comment: Please test to contact your hosting provider and maybe they can give solution for you or point your issue. If you believe that you have published your file and your connection string is correct, your site should be working fine.

Comment: @DouglasThomas I already contact hosting site they reply they do not know how to fix it

Comment: Seriously they answered it? If so, change your hosting, recommend you to use Asphostportal.com for .net hosting.